# WooCommerce weird bug when loading image

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

so ive searched through various methods on Woocommerce, turned off all my plugins (except woocommerce)

for the life of me i cannot figure out why some of the products on my shop change the primary photo upon load

for example

- Changes by itself
  http://www.bsdacademysandbox.com/peppertint/?product=bristol-3
- Works normally
  http://www.bsdacademysandbox.com/peppertint/?product=adams-3b

I've checked and rechecked the page, the information, reuploaded the images but it only occurs on some products, it looks like JS has a part to play - i cant seem to isolate where and what.

Would love some help - thank you so much in advance!

Please let me know if i can provide any other details

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate this issue on my side (reloaded page multiple times), I always see the same image after load. 

Anyway, have you tried to purge the woocommerce cache?

Comment: What version of wordpress and woocommerce you are running? What theme? This issue seems more coming from your theme. The best way to solve this kind of problems is with theme authors (If your theme is marked as compatible with WooCommerce). Try to change your permalink structure too. and check woocommerce > system status.. may be some cleaning (in tools tab).

Comment: Thanks guys , ive updated woocommerce and wordpress to latest versions, fixed the permalink. sadly the theme author is really not responsive so im getting no support from him/her :( will post update shortly as i keep testing.

im using the latest version of chrome which is showing the first image swap to the side view of the glasses

Answer (score 0):

Hey all wanted to report it was a silly mistake, need to always make sure that the image i use for the default variation to show should have the same feature image.

So basically i had a feature image, but the variation changes to the default one which also was swapping my main image on the single-product page.